# Mapping Text with Effects onto 3D object in Illustrator. Possible or not?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

I've spent a good deal of time trying to map a symbol that contains (live) text with a drop shadow onto the exterior of a ring-shaped object, and it makes part of the symbol de-render, leaving the 3D shape exposed underneath. It seems like blur effect in the drop shadow is the culprit most of the time, but I have another ring in the same document with live drop-shadowed text that renders perfectly fine. Outlined or live text doesn't seem to matter.

It also doesn't render the images (which have clipping masks). Sometimes they do render, however. Sometimes they do not. It seems almost random.

[image]

I realize Illustrator isn't made for 3D, but it's my only option, and it seems to work *some* of the time, which is what's so confusing. I can't figure out what would cause it to only partially render. Anyone have similar experiences, insight, or workarounds? Rasterizing the symbol doesn't do much. The whole thing de-renders.

Comment: Update: I was able to get the curve facing the viewer to render properly by deleting the other two sets of text and graphics. This might indicate that it just can't process the whole  thing, you'd think. I still have no idea though.

Comment: You can try tweaking the perspective or an angle in the 3D effect by 1°. Often that will cause things to render which are missing. Truth is, it's just a very unreliable effect overall and needs badly to be updated.

Comment: @Scott, I did play around with the angles and perspective in varying degrees and nothing really seemed to make them render properly except for the "solution" I found. Thanks though! Might be a useful tip in the future. Praying to the Adobe gods for an update in the mean time!

Answer (score 1):

Yes off-course it is possible. May be you are unable to get the result because you are doing it wrong way

as you created a 3d object in adobe illustrator now the 3d object has 4 parts:

1) The top
2) Bottom(which is hidden)
3) Outer Circle &
4) Inner Circle

when you applying mapping you must select the 3rd one- OUTER CIRCLE(in your case) in order to get the desired result
Here is a link of quick video demonstration I have just created for you.
I hope this may help you..

https://youtu.be/Y5iQNx58STY

Comment: Hey @Rishab.Ag, and thanks. It IS applied to the 3rd surface, and you can see that it is from the gold lines lining the top and bottom of the ring that are similarly on the symbol below. However, the text and images are mysteriously de-rendering, and *that's* the issue. I can see everything but the text and images.

Comment: hey @evaupallnight can you share this file. may be I can look into it and only then I can give you the specific reason why this de-rendering is happening.

Comment: I can't, because it's for work. (Company property, not mine to share) But perhaps I can re-create the problem in another file. Let me see what I can do!